# PHP merge multi dimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multi dimensional array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [section1] => Array
        (
            [item1] => 0
            [item2] => 0
        )
    [section2] => Array
        (
            [item27] => 0
            [item8]  => 0
        )
)
```

I am trying to merge it so it looks like this..

```
Array
(
    [item1] => 0
    [item2] => 0
    [item27] => 0
    [item8]  => 0
)
```

I know I can loop through each and them add to a new array, but is there a built in PHP function I can use instead?

Comment: as i know you must use loop function

Comment: Have you looked at `array_merge()` or `array_merge_recursive()`?

Comment: $result = array_merge(...array_values($data));